# I can't read the LY register of the gameboy

Tags: assembly, z80, gameboy

Recently I started learning how can I create games for gameboy in z80 asm, I know that there is a register in the memory ($ff44) the LY register, I tried to read that register using the instruction "ld a, ($ff44)" in hexadecimal "3a 44 ff" but when I run the game in the gameboy emulator it close the game.

If I use the intructions:
"ld hl, $ff44
ld a, (hl)", I think that it works, but why it doesn't work when I use the other instruction?

(I'm sorry, I don't speak english, so this text may be bad wrote.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GameBoy processors is not a z80. It's also not an Intel 8080. It has strong similarities with both of those, of course.

The 3A opcode does not mean `ld a, (nn)` on the GameBoy z80-like processor, it means `ld a, (hl-)` also denoted `ldd a, (hl)`, however you write it it's an instruction that uses the address from `hl` and then decrements `hl`, it doesn't take two extra code bytes as address. The 44 and FF would be seen as extra instructions, with the FF meaning `rst 7`. `ld a, (nn)` can be directly encoded but with a different opcode, namely FA.

The GameBoy processor has something else (which the z80 doesn't have) that you may be able to use: `ld a, (0xFF00 + n)` encoded as `F0 n`. It would save space and time compared to the plain `ld a, (nn)`.

Sources:

- GameBoy CPU manual http://marc.rawer.de/Gameboy/Docs/GBCPUman.pdf
- gbdev.io documentation https://gbdev.io/pandocs/CPU_Instruction_Set.html

Comment: Where can I find the gamboy processor instruction set?

Comment: @MorsaHelada: See harold's edit for a link to a manual.  (Stack Overflow doesn't notify askers when people edit their answers, so IDK if you already noticed or not.)

Comment: I have already seen it, thank you very much for helping me.